# Place menu buttons side by side in HTML/CSS

Tags: php, html, css

This is the top menu buttons of my webpage at the moment. I would like to have the buttons on the same line.

[image]

```html
<html>
        <div class = "row" style ="background-color:black;padding:0px;">
    <ul class = "menutop">
    <li><button type="button" class="navigatorbutton" id="navigatorbuttonid" onclick="swapMenuState()">Close Menu</button></li>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
            echo "<li class = \"toplistright\"><form style=\"display: inline\" action=\"Data/LogOut.php\"><button type=\"submit\" class =\"logoutbutton\">Logout</button></form></li>";
            echo "<li class = \"toplistright\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"signupbutton\" onclick=\"openSignPage()\">Sign Up</button></li>";
        }else{
            echo "<li class = \"toplistright\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"loginbutton\" onclick=\"openLoginPage()\">Login</button></li>";
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

I think the problem lies in this code part (or at least it is fixable in this code part), and if not, I will post the rest of the relevant code.  I am not super good at either of the three languages, html, php or css. I just can't see where the problem might lie.

Comment: With `<li>` you can't put buttons horizontal.

Comment: I agree it might be better to use '<span>' rather than '<li>?'

Comment: your track record on acceptance is questionable

Comment: (sorry for bad english) `.menutop li{display: inline-block;}` should solve this, or `.toplistright{display: inline-block;}` if you want to skip "Close Menu" button

Comment: Thank you @SwetaParmar. I thought I could have list items horizontally and tried lots of different things like changing, the floating variable, the border and so on for like 1 hour. Now they are side by side. I used <span> like Galvin said.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So someone just went to my account and thumbed down all my 3 previous html posts. They were not negged before. If you do that to users you should be banned.

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff why should you turn li into span ? display will do the job. Beside : <form><button> ..</form> will do fine. No need of these extra div , ul and li to achieve this layout .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CSS `display: inline-block`, like below:

```
.menutop button, .menutop form {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This put all the buttons under each other. I am sorry, I should have specified to put them horizonally. I guess I need to change from <li> to <span>.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `li` containing **Close Menu** button to last

```
<html>
    <div class = "row" style ="background-color:black;padding:0px;">
<ul class = "menutop">

    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        echo "<li class = \"toplistright\"><form style=\"display: inline\" action=\"Data/LogOut.php\"><button type=\"submit\" class =\"logoutbutton\">Logout</button></form></li>";
        echo "<li class = \"toplistright\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"signupbutton\" onclick=\"openSignPage()\">Sign Up</button></li>";
    }else{
        echo "<li class = \"toplistright\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"loginbutton\" onclick=\"openLoginPage()\">Login</button></li>";
    }
    ?>
<li><button type="button" class="navigatorbutton" id="navigatorbuttonid" onclick="swapMenuState()">Close Menu</button></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex and margin:

```css
/* reset for demo */

li {
  display: block;/* removes bullet*/
  margin:2px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0px;
}

form {
  display: inline;
}


/* ================ */
/* flex layout demo */
/* ================ */

.menutop {
  display: flex;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: auto;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

li,
button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EE2A2B, #A60A14);
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px #Ee5050;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  padding: 3px 1em;
  color:silver
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="menutop">
    <li><button type="button" class="navigatorbutton" id="navigatorbuttonid" onclick="swapMenuState()">Close Menu</button></li>
    <li class="toplistright">
      <form action="Data/LogOut.php"><button type="submit" class="logoutbutton">Logout</button></form>
    </li>
    <li class="toplistright"><button type="button" class="signupbutton" onclick="openSignPage()">Sign Up</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### edit

the list can be avoided

```css
.row {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
}

button:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: auto;
}

button:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EE2A2B, #A60A14);
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px #Ee5050;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px 1em;
  color: silver
}
```

```html
<form action="Data/LogOut.php" class="row">
  <button type="button" class="navigatorbutton" id="navigatorbuttonid" onclick="swapMenuState()">Close Menu</button>
  <button type="submit" class="logoutbutton">Logout</button>
  <button type="button" class="signupbutton" onclick="openSignPage()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

---

`float` approach

```css
.row {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 2px;
}

.navigatorbutton {
  float: left;
}

button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EE2A2B, #A60A14);
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px #Ee5050;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 3px 1em;
  color: silver
}
```

```html
<form action="Data/LogOut.php" class="row">
  <button type="button" class="navigatorbutton" id="navigatorbuttonid" onclick="swapMenuState()">Close Menu</button>
  <button type="submit" class="logoutbutton">Logout</button>
  <button type="button" class="signupbutton" onclick="openSignPage()">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So this looks nice as well, do you think I should do it this way or just use the span like I did already?

Comment: @David , sorry i do not understand about the `span`, where is it ? . what i did is a flex demo from your code .(and removed the php parts) . you can even do this from the `form` itself and just buttons.  `ul`,  `li` are useless to my opinion here. see second snippet demo. If you do not want to use flex, say so. There is possibilities with float also.

Comment: Hey, I was referring to the users that commented that I should use span instead of list, because they said that I couldn't do it with list. So I changed  my <li> elements to <span> elements instead. So from this comment, I guess you think list should be avoided. After changing to <span> I then display them as inline block and float them to the right.

Comment: @David Whatever, but mind to use CSS to style your HTML and not HTML to style HTML, **so li can be displayed inline or inline-block**. button are themselves inline-block elements, do you really need to wrap them into an extra tag  ? Anyway do not get confused, use CSS to style the proper HTML structure, else if you start to use tags for the way they look/behave, you'll end up with tag soups and headaches ;) The span won't hurt here, but use them for the right reason if you do

Comment: @David added the float approach in a last snippet. Basicly, do it simple with the minimal html and css that is really needed ;).